# java -jar tomcat install reports success but doesn't unpack war file

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application which I took over recently.  It is a web app running in Tomcat 7 in a Windows environment (Windows Server 2008 R2).  The install unpacks to its own folder structure [appName][version number]\tomcat...  and then I uninstall and re-install the service to point to the new version.  This is how it was handed over to me and I am no expert on Tomcat.

Up until about a week or 2 ago when I did my last install on UAT all has been well.  I ran java - jar [appname]-installer-[version].jar and the application installed to a new folder in the structure.  Yesterday we put the latest version live and the war file did not unpack.  The final message is a success message but although the new folder structure is created the E:[appname][version number]\tomcat\webapps folder contains an unpacked ROOT.war.

I am now convinced the problem is in the environment as it now happens on a test server which was fine before and also I tried it with a previous version of the app and this is also suffering the same issue.

I'm sure there have been no changes to the configuration of Tomcat, which makes me wonder if it may be a Windows update issue which has caused a problem ?

Does anyone have any ideas ?  I've copied the output of the false success below in case it helps ...  I will try and get details of what updates have been installed recently but I'm hoping someone may have had the same issue (or be able to point to the obvious missing ingredient, wave a magic want or ...!)

Many thanks if you can help

```
----
thisclass: Installer
installerFileName: /E:/Install/0.6.6/[appname]-installer-0.6.6.jar
Adding environment hostname: [SERVERNAME]

Reading installation manifest:
==============================
Manifest Key:Installation-Replacement-Files, value:tomcat/lib/app.properties
Manifest Key:Installation-Property-Order, value:java,env,file
Manifest Key:Installation-Name, value:[appcode]
Manifest Key:Build-Jdk, value:1.7.0_60
Manifest Key:Built-By, value:username
Manifest Key:Manifest-Version, value:1.0
Manifest Key:Installation-Version, value:0.6.6
Manifest Key:Created-By, value:Apache Maven
Manifest Key:Installation-Codebase-Files, value:
Manifest Key:Build-Date, value:20150309-1120
Manifest Key:Main-Class, value:Installer
Manifest Key:Archiver-Version, value:Plexus Archiver

Starting installation:
======================
Installation dir: E:\[appname]\0.6.6\
Installing: tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
Installing: tomcat/lib/logback.xml
Installing: tomcat/lib/app.properties
Updating tomcat/lib/app.properties
+ Installation changed:
product.name=@@product.name@@
to:
product.name=[appname]
+ Installation changed:
product.version=@@product.version@@
to:
product.version=0.6.6
+ Installation changed:
install.date=@@install.date@@
to:
install.date=Fri Apr 10 09:45:51 BST 2015
Installing: service.bat
Installing: startup.bat
Installing: shutdown.bat
Installing: tomcat/conf/server.xml
Installing: tomcat/conf/web.xml

Congratulations, installation has been successful
```

Answer (score 1):

tomcat needs the flag  `unpackWARs = true` and also `autoDeploy = true` this is done in the `server.xml`.

That log file is that the output of the "installer" (not tomcat), which seems mighty overblown btw.

What do the tomcat logs say ?  I don't think this is a windows conf issue, most likely the installer has changed.

Comment: Thanks.  These are both set to true.  I'm pretty sure it's not a Tomcat setting as it has affected 3 servers (dev, test, live) and barring sabotage no one has changed any Tomcat settings on any of them (and it worked until about 2 weeks ago)

Comment: @gringogordo what does the tomcat log say when start/stop tomcat ?

Comment: Many apologies.  I've realised that I stopped halfway through the process and panicked!  on looking for the logs it finally got through to me that it is the process of starting Tomcat that unpacks the war file and not the java install.  Doh!  Thanks again for your help (if only I was more deserving of it ;-)